# WHERE clause in MySQL for selecting all

Tags: php, mysql, sql, where-clause

I have a script in `PHP`, which selects data from a `Mysql` Database using `Select` & `Where` clause.

```
$lrn= "PU2017LN11K";
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM mcq WHERE LRN = :crn ORDER BY LRN,Sr ASC ');
$stmt->bindParam(':crn',$lrn);
$stmt->execute();
```

Now how to script the code so that it selects from all the `LRN`, using `WHERE LRN = :crn`.

I tried:

```
$lrn= "*";
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM mcq WHERE LRN = :crn ORDER BY LRN,Sr ASC ');
$stmt->bindParam(':crn',$lrn);
$stmt->execute();
```

But it didn't show any results!

It's easy to skip the `WHERE` clause if I want to show all results, but
the value of `$lrn` will be defined by the `$_GET` method.

Comment: Don't use a where clause if you want all the rows.

Comment: @chris85 I know but, value of `$lrn` will be from `$_GET` method!

Comment: I'd just build the query dynamically, if not `*` use a `where` if not dont.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal way of handling this would be:

```
$lrn= "*";
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM mcq WHERE LRN = :crn OR :crn = \'*\' ORDER BY LRN, Sr ASC ');
```

Alternatively, you could use `LIKE`:

```
$lrn = "%";
$stmt = $user_home->runQuery('SELECT * FROM mcq WHERE LRN LIKE :crn ORDER BY LRN, Sr ASC ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You want all rows, don't use a where clause. Alternatively, if you *must* use a where (something in your code or thinking/design requires it), then you can also say something like "where 1" (like the way phpMyAdmin does things all the time, for what ever reason).

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your where clause:

```
WHERE LRN = CASE WHEN :crn = '*' THEN LRN else :crn END
```

That way when the supplied :crn is '*' you will get all records.